# Using Q to create an async user input sequence

Tags: node.js, prompt, q

I am toying with [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and [promptly](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-promptly) and I am trying to ask, in a sequence, the user to input some stuff. For example :

```
What is your name? Bob
What is your age? 40
Hello Bob (40)!
```

(yes! it's a simple "Hello world!" program.)

And here is the code I am trying, directly from Q's github project page :

```
Q.fcall(promptly.prompt, "What is your name? ")
.then(promptly.prompt, "What is your age? ")
.done(function(name, age) {            
  console.log("Hello " + name + " (" + age + ")");
});
```

});

But it is not working as expected (maybe I'm reading wrong?). Whatever I try, it seems that `promptly.prompt` is listening to keystroke in parallel, and the `.done` function is called right away, resulting into a

```
/path/to/node_modules/promptly/index.js:80
         fn(null, data);
         ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
     at /path/to/node_modules/promptly/index.js:80:9
     ...
```

once I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Any idea why this is doing so and how I can accomplish what I'm trying to do?

#### ** Edit **

Basically, what my end goal would be to create a reusable function invoked like so :

```
promptAll({ 
    'name': "What is your name? ", 
    'age': "What is your age? "
}).done(function(input) {
    console.log(input);  // ex: { name: "Bob", age: 40 }
});
```

#### ** Update **

Here's my working solution, I had to use `nfcall` as suggested by [WiredPraine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210030/using-q-to-create-an-async-user-input-sequence/19210967?noredirect=1#19210967) :

```
function multiPrompt(args) {
  function _next() {
    if (keys.length) {
      var key = keys.pop();
      Q.nfcall(promptly.prompt, args[key]).done(function(value) {
        result[key] = value;
        _next();
      });
    } else {
      def.resolve(result);
    }
  };
  var def = Q.defer();  
  var keys = _.keys(args).reverse();
  var result = {};

  _next();

  return def.promise;
};
```

(**Note** : I am using Underscore, but the same can be achieved with a standard object iterator.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are two approaches.

First, you'd need to use `nfcall` so that Q uses the NodeJS conventions for callbacks.

But, as the functions aren't promises, you'll need to handle the chaining and synchronous behavior slightly differently.

In the first example, `start1`, the code creates an instance of `defer` and returns it as the promise. When the `prompt` function returns, it `resolve`s the deferred object instance and passes the `value` of the function (ideally the prompt). It should also handle errors, etc. in "real" code.

In both examples, I've added a function to grab the result of the the promise resolving. It's not passed as parameters to the last `done` instance. The function passed to `done` will execute as soon as the first promise is resolved (after the `prompt` has returned in this case).

```
var promptly = require('promptly');
var Q = require('q');

// make a simple deferred/promise out of the prompt function
var prompter = function(text) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    promptly.prompt(text, function(err, value) {
       deferred.resolve(value);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};

// this option just uses the promise option to prompt for name.
function start1() {
    prompter("What is your name?").then(function(name) {
        prompter("Your age?").then(function(age) {
            console.log("Hello " + name + " (" + age + ")");
        });
    });
}

// this one uses the nfcall funcitonality to directly call the 
// promptly.prompt function (and waits for a callback).
function start2() {
    Q.nfcall(promptly.prompt, "What is your name? ")
        .then(function(name) {
                Q.nfcall(promptly.prompt, "What is your age? ")
                    .done(function(age) {
                        console.log("Hello " + name + " (" + age + ")");
                    });
        });
}

//start1();
```

Comment: From the Q's doc : "There are two ways to chain promises. You can chain promises either inside or outside handlers. The ... two examples are equivalent." I was going for the second example, as I want to create a generic reusable function prompting the user for things. I am sure that there's a solution with Q handling this case already...

Comment: But, `promptly.prompt` isn't a promise and you need to have a callback function to accept the return value. I demonstrated techniques for wrapping it into a promise and using `nfcall`.

Comment: Yes, the second example works. This is why I came up with the solution from my last update. :) Works great! I actually added more features for more controllability.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the answers here can be added to for anyone seeking alternatives to solving the general problem of getting command line user input from node.

Firstly, I personally feel there is merit to moving towards the ES6 Promises API. Although not natively available yet in Node, there is a great polyfill: https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise.

Secondly, I have come to like an alternative user prompting module: https://github.com/flatiron/prompt

Now assuming there exist methods 'addUserToDb', 'printUser' and 'printError' that in turn return promises, the following example is possible:

```
var prompt = require('node-prompt');
var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;

var promptUser = function(schema) {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
    prompt.get(schema, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  };
};

promptUser(["name", "password"])
  .then(addUserToDb)
  .then(printUser)
  .catch(printError)
```

I've written many 'scripts' now using this method and have found it very nice to work with and easy to maintain / adapt.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for sharing!